# Unable to get full HTML of a page, it stops at a certain point

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download the [HTML of page](http://www.posh24.se/kandisar). After it downloads I try to Log it. Everything goes smoothly but the HTML stops at a certain point every time, even though it has a lot more HTML to show.

I tried using a different page, my page which just has some instructions for my Company and it worked perfectly. Is there a limit maybe? I tried it with urlconnection.connect(), and without it and there is no difference.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadHTML extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            URL url;
            String result = "";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data!=-1){
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Fail";
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String Result = "";
        DownloadHTML task = new DownloadHTML();

        try {
            Result = task.execute("http://www.posh24.se/kandisar").get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("URL", Result);
    }
}
```

---

Here is the splitting and it wont work.

```
try {
            Result = task.execute("http://www.posh24.se/kandisar").get();
            String[] splitStrings = Result.split("<div class=\"channelListEntry\">");
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img src=\"(.*?)\"");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(splitStrings[0]);
            while (m.find()){
                CelebUrls.add(m.group(1));
            }
            p = Pattern.compile("alt=\"(.*?)\"");
            m = p.matcher(splitStrings[0]);
            while (m.find()){
                CelebNames.add(m.group(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("URL", Arrays.toString(CelebUrls.toArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't log using Logcat. It has a maximal length for performance reasons. Log somewhere else, like in the app

Comment: You should not use a `String` to save the content, use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.

Comment: You are reading it char by char, it is slow as hell, use the buffer for reading, this will speed up process a lot.

Comment: @GameDev Cro, Hi, as Zun said there is a max length for performance reasons. Use StringBuffer, even StringBuilder will do the same but StringBuffer is Thread Safe...Thank you

Comment: @VarmaLanke OK, i used a String split. I made an ArrayList and added separate sections with just the names of the celebrities and when I go ahead to print, it shows an empty Array.

Answer (score 0):

Modifing your method like this will give you the content of the html page in `UTF-8` format.
(In this case its `UTF-8` because the page is encoded like that, in doubt you can pass `Charset.forName("utf-8")` as second paramter to the constructor of `InputStreamReader`)

When testing you example implementation I only got some output with various unreadable characters.

*Ignore the class and the method changes, I only made them to have a standalone example.*

```
public class ParsingTest {

    static String doInBackground(String address) {
        URL url;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(1000);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(address);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null){

                result.append(line);
                result.append("\n");
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            return result.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Fail";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = doInBackground("http://www.posh24.se/kandisar");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

---

If the only part that interest you are the images of the top100, you can just adjust the while loop to:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null){
    if (line.contains("<div class=\"channelListEntry\">")) {
        reader.readLine();
        reader.readLine();

        line = reader.readLine().trim();

        // At this points its probably easier to use a List<String> for the result instead
        result.append(line);
        result.append("\n");
    }

    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

This is only a simplied example based on the current design of the page,
 where the `img` comes 3 lines after the declaration of the `div`.

---

If you want to you can also just extract the `url` of the image and the `alt` description directly at this point. Instead of using complicated regex you could rely on the `String#indexOf` instead.

```
private static final String SRC = "src=\"";
private static final String ALT = "\" alt=\"";
private static final String END = "\"/>";

public static void extract(String image) {

    int index1 = image.indexOf(SRC);
    int index2 = image.indexOf(ALT);
    int index3 = image.indexOf(END);

    System.out.println(image);
    System.out.println(image.substring(index1 + SRC.length(), index2));
    System.out.println(image.substring(index2 + ALT.length(), index3));
}
```

Note that if you directly process the content from the page your app does not require the memory to store the full page.